# Tkinter Widgets not disappearing after command for another widget is passed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I need the previous label to disappear or be destroyed, soon as the command for the second label is passed (by pressing another button). I don't want widgets to lag behind, only to be shadowed by a new one, i need them to go completely.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('800x600+0+0')
f1=Frame(root, width=700, height=200, bg='green')
f1.pack()
f2=Frame(root, width=700, height=200, bg='yellow')
f2.pack()

def hello():
    l1=Label(f2,text='Hello button pressed', fg='red').pack()
def bye():
    l2=Label(f2,text='Secondly, Bye button pressed', fg='blue').pack()

b1=Button(f1, text='Hello', command=hello).pack()
b2=Button(f1, text='Bye', command=bye).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no reason for the labels to disappear, all your code does is pack a new label underneath the last one. You'd be better off creating one label and changing the text of that label using the `.config()` method.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('800x600+0+0')
f1=Frame(root, width=700, height=200, bg='green')
f1.pack()
f2=Frame(root, width=700, height=200, bg='yellow')
f2.pack()

# label to change
lbl = Label(f2, text='', fg='red')
lbl.pack()


def hello():
    global lbl
    # edit label text
    lbl.config(text='Hello button pressed', fg='red')


def bye():
    global lbl
    lbl.config(text='Secondly, Bye button pressed', fg='blue')


b1=Button(f1, text='Hello', command=hello).pack()
b2=Button(f1, text='Bye', command=bye).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That worked well, but is there a way in which the label (and other widgets) can be 'destroyed', apart from the config method? I ask so because i have several widgets (buttons, labels, entry boxes, etc) that i need to 'to disappear' to pave way for other widgets as invoked by another command. its not just a label. the code is quiet large, used a label above as an example.

Comment: Use .pack_forget() . This just 'unpacks' the widget rather than destroying it, so it's still there if you need to pack it again. If you actually want to destroy it so it can't be packed again, call .destroy() on the widget.